# Laravel Eloquent - get distinct values of one column

Tags: laravel-5, eloquent

I have a MongoDB collection organized like the following document:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("55f699bb1638cf0f4ba139f1"), "code" : 169, "categories" : "Consulenti del lavoro", "listing" : "B", "macrocategory" : "Consulenti" }
```

I need to get an array of the macrocategory field, but it's assigned to multiple documents and I need only one occurence of each of them. I tried using distinct in my Eloquent query, but I can't use it as I don't know which is the return value.

My query now, which returns the macrocategories multiple times:

```
$macrocategories = Category::orderBy('macrocategory','asc')->get();
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You suppose to use distinct when you want an entire row to be unique,when you want a specific column to be unique you should use `GROUP BY`

I guess the distinct would be the same as yours `order by` coulmn -

`$macrocategories = Category::orderBy('macrocategory','asc')->groupBy('macrocategory')->get();`

BTW if you have columns that you don't need you should use `select` and fetch only the columns you do.